# Non printable chars in Eclipse window header (DBeaver plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts

I have non printable chars in eclipse ide window header, check screenshot. Locale ru_RU.UTF8. Webdings and windings fonts installed for ubuntu - dont known if java need some additional installation steps, also dont know is this chars belong to this fonts. Java version openjdk-8 on ubuntu17.10, default from repo. Also tried oracle-8-jre.

Non ascii chars work fine in editor.

Have read similar questions and google for it.

This not so important but interesting to fix it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: 0x0A is the Linux end of line character, as you said, non printable but eclipse shows it hex value anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a bug. Just such header with \n in that plugin.

@Luis should add comment as answer.